# GetWindowRect without titlebar

Tags: c#, windows, screen-scraping

I want to get client area, I know the default answer is GetClientRect but what I get from that function is a rectangle starting at (0,0). So I can't use GetClientRect with CopyFromScreen.

Is there a way to get absolute coordinates with GetClientRect OR somehow learning the titlebar size etc. while using GetWindowRect?

I am using C#.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Use [PointToScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen.aspx) to transform client coordinates to screen coordinates: